# text to timestamp in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In the view  I have a `text` column which contains a timestamp in this format `'20/03/2018 00:00'` and I'm trying to make a selection with a between clause but it's not working

```
SELECT id,entry_date
FROM v_view 
WHERE entrada BETWEEN to_timestamp('20/03/2018 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY')::timestamp and to_timestamp('22/03/2018 00:00')::timestamp
order entry_date
```

with this error message

```
ERROR:  el operador no existe: text >= timestamp without time zone
LINE 3: WHERE entry_date BETWEEN to_timestamp('20/03/2018 00:00','DD/MM.
```

Comment: If the `entrada` column contains date like `20/03/2018 14:20`, You probably need `... WHERE to_timestamp(entrada, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN ...`.

Comment: Why on earth are you storing timestamps in a `text` column?

Answer (score 2):

you need to convert the `entrada` column value to a timestamp.

Also: casting the result of `to_timestamp()` to  a `timestamp` is useless because `to_timestamp()` already returns a `timestamp`

```
SELECT id,entry_date
FROM v_view 
WHERE to_timestamp(entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') 
      BETWEEN to_timestamp('20/03/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
          and to_timestamp('22/03/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
order entry_date;
```

I prefer to use ANSI SQL timestamp literals over the `to_timestamp` function:

```
SELECT id,entry_date
FROM v_view 
WHERE to_timestamp(entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') 
      BETWEEN timestamp '2018-03-20 00:00:00' 
          and timestamp '2018-03-22 00:00:00'
order entry_date
```

---

Do not store date, time or timestamp values in a `text` or `varchar` column. You should define that column as `timestamp` then you don't need to convert anything and you don't need to deal with invalid timestamp values in that column.

Comment: +1. Let me just warn that'll avoid index usage, so follow @a_horse_with_no_name advice and store timestamp as timestamps :)